# Thread JFrame needs to update JTextPane

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, jtextpane

I have following code. I need to update JTextPane object when result variable changes. Result variable changes properly, it's tested. This code works as thread. I really doesn't have idea how to solve it, maybe any eventlistener would be good there?

```
public class GeneralShopFrame implements Runnable, Observer{
    private double result = 0 ;
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    JTextPane jtp = new JTextPane();
    @Override
    public void run() {   
        String[] tab = { "Data_0.txt", "0" } ;
        GeneralShopThread gst = new GeneralShopThread(tab);
        Runnable r = gst;
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();

        GeneralShopFrame gsf = new GeneralShopFrame();
        gst.addObserver(gsf);       

        jtp.setText("Current value of result is " + result);  //I NEED UPDATE IT

        buttonPanel.add(jtp); 

        buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));

        jf.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    public GeneralShopFrame(String[] args) {
    }    

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {

        result = (double) arg;
        System.out.println(makespan);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `setText(...)` on the JTextPane from within the update method, taking care to be sure that it is called on the Swing event thread, e.g., from within a Runnable that is queued on the event thread using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`. e.g.,

```
// code not tested
@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        result = (double) arg;
        jtp.setText("Current value of result is " + result);
    });
}
```

But you state that it doesn't work, and your code shows why: you're creating **another** GeneralShopFrame object within your run method above, one that is not displayed, and because of this, you're notifying the **wrong** GeneralShopFrame object of changes to an observable. Don't do this. Instead perhaps pass the current GeneralShopFrame object or `this` into this call:

```
gst.addObserver(this);
```